# Please help me solve this (f+g)(-2) when f(x)= x-3 and g(x)=x+1?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can anyone help me solve this or please post a step by step text on how to get this problem set up. I am not understanding why I cannot get the right answer for this one. It should be -6 but I am not getting -6 I am getting all kinds of crazy answers.

Comment: Will you please post your solution so that we can look through it and give you advice?

Answer (score 2):

When they ask you $(f+g)(-2)$ it is better for you to think of $(f+g)$ as another function. Let's define a function $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)$. Notice that $f=f(x)$. This is just notation, which means that $f$ depends on the variable $x$.

You'll end up with $h(x)=f(x)+g(x)=x-3+x+1=2x-2$. Then it is easy to see that $h(-2)=(f(x)+g(x))(-2) = 2(-2)-2 = -6$.

Answer (score 1):

we have $f+g=x-3+x+1=2x-2$ plugging for $x$ $-2$ in the term we get $2(-2)-2=-6$